# CSS margins on blackberry browser

Tags: css, blackberry, radio-button, margin, vertical-alignment

I have the following radio buttons on my form (I pulled all my CSS in-line so you can see):

```
<div style="border:1px solid white;">
<input type="radio" style="margin:20px 5px 20px 15px;" name="daypick" value="1d">
<span style="color:white;font:normal 1.5em arial;">1 Day</span>
</div>
```

In chrome, the radio button is vertically centered in the div by default, but it sits at the bottom of the div on my Blackberry. Can anyone help with vertical alignment please?

That bottom 20px in the input's margin is not doing the trick (but it does in Chrome). Need a different method.

thanks!
John

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
  display: inline-block;
```

or

```
 display: block;
```

to your input radio button.

Comment: yeah - I had tried that already. no difference. thanks though!